# Why is Ubuntu crashing my macbook when I try to install it in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, macbook

I am majoring in Technology Management at Texas A&M University.  As part of my DevOps class we were asked to install VirtualBox and install the Ubuntu disk image (.ISO).  I get all the way to the finalization of the Ubuntu installation on VirtualBox and it crashes my entire computer.  I have tried disabling the Audio and and confirmed that everything is supported by my computer.  I am running a Macbook Air (2018) with an i7 dual core.

Comment: A good start is what version of Ubuntu are you trying to install?

Comment: How much RAM did you allocate for Ubuntu?